# How to implement the "auto pairing of quotes" feature in custom mode in ace-editor

Tags: autocomplete, quotes, ace-editor

I want to add "auto pairing of quotes" feature in my custom mode. I find the solution that add editor.setBehavioursEnabled(true), but it seems like only work for existing mode. I know I perhaps miss some code in my custom mode. Can anyone point out which code is response for this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use cstyle behavior similar to the way javascript mode does see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.9/lib/ace/mode/javascript.js#L47 https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.9/lib/ace/mode/behaviour/cstyle.js